# How to compare two ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I'm making a Lotto program.

How do I know if one ArrayList contains all the numbers from the other ArrayList?

The way I tried.

```
ArrayList<String> newNumbers = new ArrayList<>();//Define Lotto Scope
ArrayList<String> resultNumbers = new ArrayList<>(); //Only 6 numbers 
ArrayList<String> includingNumbers= new ArrayList<>(); //Number to Include

 public void applyStaticNumbers(){

   for (int i = 1; i < 46; i++) {
        newNumbers.add("" + i);
    }

   Collections.shuffle(newNumbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        resultNumbers.add(newNumbers.get(i));
    }

   resultNumbers.sort(Comparator.comparing(Double::parseDouble)); //sort Numbers

   if (resultNumbers.contains(includingNumbers.get(0))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            textViews.get(i).setText(resultNumbers.get(i));
        }
    } else {//If not included, restart.
        newNumbers.clear();
        resultNumbers.clear();
        applyStaticNumbers();
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your lists are of type `String`? It would simplify your solution significantly if they were of type `Integer` (it's how an `int` primitive is stored in a collection; see [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)). Also, it should be noted that `Integer` is an _Object_, and as such ___should not___ be compared with the `==` operator (there are reasons for it, but none that you'll use).

Comment: Because I am a beginner... Thank you. And as I add several numbers, I have memory problem and I am working on it...

Comment: Ah, that's due to the call to `applyStaticNumbers()` in the `else` block. What's happening is the method is being called again recursively (something good to read up on). To solve it, I would make `applyStaticNumbers` return a `boolean` (return `true` by default, but `false` in the `else` statement, and have another method determine whether `applhyStaticNumbers` should be run again.

Comment: It was very helpful. I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `containsAll` method

```
includingNumbers.containsAll(resultNumbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use removeall method

Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("x","y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d"));
        Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a","b",  "d", "e", "f", "x", "y"));

```
    List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>(listOne);
    List<String> destinationList = new ArrayList<String>(listTwo);


    sourceList.removeAll( listTwo );
    destinationList.removeAll( listOne );
```